# what's the time complexity of this solution to find a rotation point (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, binary-search

The question was to find the index of a rotation point, like this:

`var letters = ['c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b']; // -> 3 because it's the index of 'a'`

I was trying to do it in O(log n) time, does using slice make it O(n log n)?

Here's my solution:

```
var findRotationPointLogN = function(array, addedLength) {
  var midpointIndex = Math.floor(array.length / 2);
  var right = array.slice(midpointIndex);
  var left = array.slice(0, midpointIndex);
  if (array[midpointIndex] < array[midpointIndex - 1]) {
    if (addedLength) {
      return midpointIndex + addedLength;
    } else {
      return midpointIndex;
    }
  } else if (array[midpointIndex] > array[0]) {
    if (addedLength) {
      return findRotationPointLogN(right, addedLength + left.length);
    } else {
      return findRotationPointLogN(right, left.length);
    }
  } else if (array[midpointIndex] < array[0]) {
    return findRotationPointLogN(left, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "rotation point"?  The center? That should be `e` anyways. What is your question?

Comment: Yes, `slice` takes `O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

It's not the point where the letter is smaller than the previous letter?

```js
const r = l => l.reduceRight((p, c, i, a) => a[i-1] && a[i].charCodeAt(0) < a[i-1].charCodeAt(0) ? i : p, 0);
console.log(r(['c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b']));
```

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question at all.

Comment: Yeah, I read more after I posted this. I guess my solution is O(n) and the question was attempting O(log n).